# Call function in namespace

Tags: c++

Before I start, yes I know what I have done is 'illegal', but I need to know what I would do to write this properly.

I have this code:

```
namespace PrisonBreak
{
    void Waterfall(int client)
     {
            int* origin = (int*) (0xF4499C + 0x3700 * client);
            origin[0] = 0xC5DE0CA8;
            origin[1] = 0x4432BAEF;
            origin[2] = 0x44C0C828;
     }
}
```

And I am trying to call it in a separate header like this:

```
PrisonBreak::Waterfall(i);
```

Unfortunately I get this error when compiling:

> error 277: name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name

Just wondering, what is the proper way of writing the first section of code so I can call it like the above without any errors.

Thanks :)

Comment: Compiles for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5d04cb045bff524

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: try passing an argument inside the function

Comment: I don't understand how you think we can unambiguously determine your intention from code that, by your own admission, does not represent it!

Comment: Why are you trying to call a function from within a header?

Comment: Sounds like the intended call is placed at namespace scope in the header. Put it inside a function, or in the initializer expression for something. At namespace scope you can only have **declarations**, not commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *call* your function like this:

```
PrisonBreak::Waterfall(5);
```

You certainly can put any number instead of `5` here.

Or you can pass this function to another function:

```
SomeFunc(PrisonBreak::Waterfall);
```

Comment: my bad, I didn't write it correctly. I am trying to call it like PrisonBreak::Waterfall(i); and it still doesn't work :P

Comment: @alboyiscool, it doesn't work how? Still the same way? Are you including all the headers properly?

Comment: Yes, i have included all my headers inside the main cpp file so there's definitely no issue there. When i compile it complains that the function has to be a class or a namespace name, so how would that work?

Comment: @alboyiscool, you'd better provide a MCVE as when I compile the code in my answer, it works OK: http://codepad.org/VjoUQPSJ

Comment: @alboyiscool - If the code is in different headers, you have to include them *in the right order*.

Comment: nvm, @BoPersson's suggestion fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is that you're calling your function wrong.

This works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace PrisonBreak
{
        void waterfall(int a)
        {
                std::cout << a << std::endl;
        }
}

int main()
{
        PrisonBreak::waterfall(5);
        return 0;
}
```